# Construction of a net and the usage of Axiom of Choice

Tags: proof-explanation, axiom-of-choice, nets

I read in a homepage about [nets](https://algebrology.github.io/sequences-hausdorff-spaces-and-nets/), where the author gives an example (minor modification for context)

> **Example**. Given a topological space $X$ and a point $x\in X$, let $N_x$ denote the directed set of neighborhoods of $x$ - orderded by reverse inclusion.  We can construct a net $(x_U)_{U\in N_x}$ by choosing a point $x_U\in U$ for each $U\in N_x$. (Notice that this action requires the Aciom of Choice). [..]

What I do not understand is, why the Axiom of Choice is needed (isn't it superfluous?). For every $U\in N_x$, you can "choose" a point $x_U\in U$. This is possible, simply because that each set in $N_x$ contains a least one element (including $x$ itself), i.e. every set in $N_x$ is non-empty. So, the existence of a such point is justified. If I am wrong, please let me know.

Comment: You are correct that this does not require the axiom of choice. As you point out, one can simply pick $x_U = x\in U$ for each $U$. Be careful, though, about saying that we can pick elements because every $U$ is non-empty. In general, this is exactly the sort of thing that we need the axiom of choice for. (I.e. the axiom of choice says that given a family of non-empty sets, then there exists a choice function.)

Comment: @o.h. Can't we be sure that $x_U\in U$ can be chosen for which $x_U\neq x$ for each $U\in N_x$ - without using the Axiom of Choice? I mean, $U$ is itself an open set containing $x$, so it surely must contain other than $x$ itself (unless $U$ is a singleton??).

Answer (score 2):

The statement "If $X$ is a family of sets and each member of $X$ is non-empty, then we can choose an element from each member of $X$" is the statement of the Axiom of Choice.

Your suggestion that we always choose $x$ is fine, but it is somewhat unhelpful if you try to understand nets, since it's a constant net. Some definitions in topology will talk about sequences or nets which do not use their intended limit.

For example, $x$ is isolated if $\{x\}$ is open, but if it is not isolated, then there is a net $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ such that $x_i\neq x$ for all $i\in I$ and $\lim x_i=x$. But for this we need the axiom of choice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I partially understand it, but I still struggle to understand it completely. I can see what you meant by the constant net, which I did not want it. If $U$ belongs to $N_x$, does it not indicate that $U$ contains other than the point $x$? If yes, then you can choose a point $y$ in $U$ for which $y\neq x$.

Comment: A net is constant if all the points on the net are the same, or at least on a cobounded subset of the index set (eventually constant, in that case). Just like a constant sequence would be a sequence with just one value. As for being able to choose, how? Why? The axiom of choice is the mechanism through which we choose from infinitely many sets at the same time.

Comment: Okay, I think I am getting a better picture of it. The Axiom of Choice is needed, simply because we are talking about choosing infinitely many times, because there are infinitely many sets in $N_x$. It is like, when you prove something concerning $n=1,2,...$, you do not have to check for every single number (first check for n= 1, then check n=2, then check for n=3, etc. etc it takes for ever), and will be saved by using the mathematical principle of induction by doing simple steps, right?

Comment: Not exactly. But it's very subtle, so it's best, I think, to put this aside for now.